# Generate data frames with Loops R susbet

Tags: r, loops, subset

```
head(per1)
       flowcorrelativeid nrodocumento grupo_fict cod_jer
21            431167     49574917          3      1146
49            546385     54692750          1      320
50            546388     48552750          2      320
54            454662     54731807          8      104
58            484984     17549854          4      104
78            360883     46867674          1      101
79            360883     56864674          7      101
80            360883     46867668          1      258
81            360883     66847668          5      258
81            360883     57364201          1      178
88            360883     58364201          6      178
```

I have this data frame, and I would like to generate a lot of subset of this data frame like this:

```
data_frame_104_1=subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==104 & per1$grupo_fict=1)
data_frame_104_2=subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==104 & per1$grupo_fict=2)
.
.
.
data_frame_104_8=subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==104 & per1$grupo_fict=8)
```

and then

```
data_frame_101_1=subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==101 & per1$grupo_fict=1)
data_frame_101_2=subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==101 & per1$grupo_fict=2)
.
.
.
data_frame_101_8=subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==101 & per1$grupo_fict=8)
```

I need this for each "cod_jer" (52 groups) and each "grupo_fict"(8 groups)

How can i do?

Any suggestion?

THANKS!

Comment: Just use `split` i.e. `split(per1, list(per1$cod_jer, per1$grupo_fict), drop=TRUE)` and get a `list` of `data.frames`  BTW, if you need to summarize based on these two columns, you can do this without any `split` using the `group_by` operations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a loop you could try sth. like this:

```
grupo_fict_groups = as.numeric(names(table(per1$grupo_fict)))
cod_jer_groups = as.numeric(names(table(per1$cod_jer)))

data.frame = data.frame(NA)

for(i in 1:length(cod_jer_groups) ){
  for(j in 1:length(grupo_fict_groups)){
    data.frame = subset(per1,per1$cod_jer==cod_jer_groups[i] & per1$grupo_fict==grupo_fict_groups[j]) 
    assign_string = paste("data_frame",cod_jer_groups[i],grupo_fict_groups[j],sep = "_")
    assign(assign_string,data.frame)
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem, can you up vote my answer then and mark the question as answered!?